# a href is not working for dynamic url in mpdf

Tags: php, mpdf

I am getting problem in anchor tag while export to PDF.Anchor tag is working for static url like http:google.com but it is not working for dynamic url.I am using mpdf module for PDF.

```
$url = $fullBaseUrl.'/designers/attachment/time/'.$value['filetime'].'/uploadTab/imgattach'; 
// http://localhost/msme_latest/designers/attachment/time/1394432246/uploadTab/imgattach     

$html= '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$value['filename'].'</a>';        

// echo $html; die;

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
```

When i echo my code $html it is giving my link properly.But when i export this code in PDF it is not giving any kind of link PDF.
Any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Ip address instead of localhost or use Live server url it is working for me

```
<?php
$fullBaseUrl = "http://127.0.0.1/meme_latest";
$url = $fullBaseUrl.'/designers/attachment/time/'.$value['filetime'].'/uploadTab/imgattach'; 
            //(http://localhost/msme_latest/designers/attachment/time/1394432246/uploadTab/imgattach)     
            $html= '<a href="'.$url.'">Test link</a>';        

            //echo $html; die;

include("../mpdf.php");

$mpdf=new mPDF(); 

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

For solve this problem you have to make just i change in mpdf.php

Actual Code is in mpdf.php on line no.20146

```
if(isset($vetor[1]) and $vetor[1] != '') //LINK
{
  if (strpos($vetor[1],".") === false && strpos($vetor[1],"@") !== 0) //assuming every external link has a dot indicating extension (e.g: .html .txt .zip www.somewhere.com etc.) 
  {
    //Repeated reference to same anchor?
    /*
    while(array_key_exists($vetor[1],$this->internallink)) $vetor[1]="#".$vetor[1];
        $this->internallink[$vetor[1]] = $this->AddLink();
        $vetor[1] = $this->internallink[$vetor[1]];
    */
  }
  $this->HREF = $vetor[1];                  // HREF link style set here ******
}
```

and you have just comment line of code (line number:20151 to 20153)

```
        /*
        while(array_key_exists($vetor[1],$this->internallink)) $vetor[1]="#".$vetor[1];
            $this->internallink[$vetor[1]] = $this->AddLink();
            $vetor[1] = $this->internallink[$vetor[1]];
        */
```

and your pdf will accept all link include "localhost" and other external links.

Comment: Bro! You are genius!